# Android - Can not open fragment a second time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm opening a `fragment` and soon after closing it.

It opens and closes no problem the first time but the second time it tries to open it gives a `NullPointerException`.

To open the `fragment` with `SomeFrag` class that extends `Fragment`. To close it I call `closeFrag()` method.

```
public class SomeFrag extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.somefrag, container, false); // line with error
        return mRootview;
    }

    public void closeFrag(){
        ((ViewGroup)mRootview.getParent()).removeView(mRootview);
    }
}
```

Why am I not able to open the fragment a second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a Fragment you should use a transaction, for instance

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentInstance).commit();
```

Comment: how do i get the fragmentInstance? I tried `Fragment frag = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.llFrag);` but I end up with a NullPointerException error.

Comment: got it, i used this, `mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();`

Comment: the easy thing to do is to keep it as a member. If you call that snippet from the fragment's class, you should be able to use the keyoword `this`

Comment: do i get points for answering my question before getting the answer?!?